# sp php send parameters mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to sp parameter via php mysql I send in.
This is my code

```
function sendSpId()
{
    global $id;
    global $connection;
    $sql = "CALL `sp_st_SelectUserAll`($id)";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die(mysqli_error($connection)); // TODO: better error handling
    }
    //loop the result set
    return mysqli_fetch_array($result);

}
```

This is my connection

```
<?php
 $serverName = "localhost";
 $userName = "root";
 $pass = "";
 $dbName = "univercity";

 $connection = mysqli_connect($serverName, $userName, $pass, $dbName);
 mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");
 if ( !$connection ) {
    die( 'connect error: '.mysqli_connect_error() );
 }


?>
```

And this is my sp

```
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `id`= id;
END
```

And the variable $ id is received by session

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```

But when I run the project I get the following error is

```
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

thank you

Comment: Can you try running the command without the database name in quote? Try running `SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = $id`

Comment: No it does not run

Comment: Can you tell me the what the SQL error is?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tamrin\function\clsFunc.php on line 27

Comment: That means that it could not return a result, so the query failed. Check the name of the table and also the name of the column. The names have to be case-sensitive exact.

Comment: one does not write SPs for trivial queries like that